# Expected performance of tries vs bucket arrays with constant load-factor

Tags: arrays, performance, complexity-theory, trie

I know that I can simply use bucket array for associative container if I have uniformly distributed integer keys or keys that can be mapped into uniformly distributed integers. If I can create the array big enough to ensure a certain load factor (which assumes the collection is not too dynamic), than the expected number of collisions for a key will be bounded, because this is simply hash table with identity hash function.

**Edit:** I view strings as equivalent to positional fractions in the range [0..1]. So they can be mapped into any integer range by multiplication and taking floor of the result.

I can also do prefix queries efficiently, just like with tries. I presume (without knowing a proof) that the expected number of empty slots corresponding to a given prefix that have to be skipped sequentially before the first bucket with at least one element is reached is also going to be bounded by constant (again depending on the chosen load factor).

And of course, I can do stabbing queries in worst-case constant time, and range queries in solely output sensitive linear expected time (if the conjecture of denseness from the previous paragraph is indeed true).

What are the advantages of a tries then?

If the distribution is uniform, I don't see anything that tries do better. But I may be wrong.

If the distribution has large uncompensated skew (because we had no prior probabilities or just looking at the worst case), the bucket array performs poorly, but tries also become heavily imbalanced, and can have linear worst case performance with strings of arbitrary length. So the use of either structure for your data is questionable.

So my question is - *what are the performance advantages of tries over bucket arrays that can be formally demonstrated? What kind of distributions elicit those advantages?*

I was thinking of distributions with self-similar structure at different scales. I believe those are called fractal distributions, of which I confess to know nothing. May be then, if the distribution is prone to clustering at every scale, tries can provide superior performance, by keeping the load factor of each node similar, adding levels at dense regions as necessary - something that bucket arrays can not do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tries are good if your strings share common prefixes. In that case, the prefix is stored only once and can be queried with linear performance in the output string length. In a bucket array, all strings with the same prefixes would end up close together in your key space, so you have very skewed load where most buckets are empty and some are huge.

More generally, tries are also good if particular patterns (e.g. the letters `t` and `h` together) occur often. If there are many such patterns, the order of the trie's tree nodes will typically be small, and little storage is wasted.

Comment: By sharing common prefixes, you mean dense clustering of the keys in several sub-intervals. And probably recursively manifesting. Is there a formal model - distribution or anything, that characterizes this kind of phenomenon. I mean we are talking about some kind of random input, right. Or is it something that is entirely artificial in nature, e.g. related to human language?  Can tries be used for keys that are not text per se, but strings of things in the more abstract sense?

Comment: Of course tries can be used for strings of things, but they work better if the alphabet is small. Just ones and zeros works, 26 letters works, 256 different octets in an IP address still works, but the larger the alphabet, the more wasteful a trie becomes.

Comment: Ok, if I may summarize what you implied in your response. For uniform distribution, for stabbing queries, tries perform no worse than balanced search trees, but for highly skewed distributions, they perform better than bucket arrays. Some sort of compromise. Also, for prefix queries, etc., they perform better than balanced search trees when the distribution is skewed. I wished some pointers that would elicit the "common prefix" phenomenon observed with strings. That is, how its influence on the performance of such structures can be formally quantified, but your answer is enough.

Comment: Just forgot something. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of tries I can think of is insertion. Bucket array may need to be resized at some point and this is expensive operation. So worst-case insertion time into trie is much better than into bucket array.

Another thing is that you need to map string to fraction to be used with bucket arrays. So if you have short keys, theoretically trie can be more efficient, because you don't need to do the mapping.

Comment: You are right about the insertion, but I wanted to leave this out of the discussion. Assume, as I said, that the data has some known average size, not-too-dynamic one. I.e., the number of billing records made in a telephone company per day. I also think that the insertion can be de-amortized, at the expense of keeping the old array for a while after allocating the new one, and moving a few records from it after each insertion.

Comment: Regarding the mapping of the keys, the string itself is a left-aligned bit pattern, just as a binary positional fraction in the interval [0..1]. It is in fact, in a sense, a fraction. All you need to do is take the leading bits (from the first characters in the string) and pad them with 0 to the right, if the string is too short. This is enough to map to a fixed-size bit pattern of integer in some interval. It will be a power of two interval, but this is a choice we are allowed to make.